# How is the time complexity O(N^2) here?

Tags: java, time, complexity-theory, analysis

I already know that the answer to this question is `O(N^2)` but I am not able to see how. I know the for loop runs `N` times, but how can it run `N^2` times?

```
public static String rev(String s) {
    String r = "";
    int N = s.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        r = s.charAt(i) + r;
    }
    return r;
}
```

Comment: why is the answer O(N^2)? That seems wrong

Comment: @ControlAltDel that's what I'm wondering here, I would think it would be N but this was an exam question and according to the professor that is the right answer.

Comment: charAt has to have it's own iteration/loop to look for the character in the same string passed to the function

Comment: Then ask you professor to explain this. He/she may be counting s.charAt(i) as another loop (O(n)), but it isn't. It is O(1).

Comment: @SteveHynding charAt is O(1), just like myArray[i] is O(1)

Comment: Ah, I should have recognized that

Comment: Just have a look at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/3972/string-manipulation-complexity, the complexity comes from the String concatenation, not from `charAt()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Java, `String` concatenation `r = s.charAt(i) + r` in a loop is `O(N^2)`, because `Strings` are immutable - a new copy of the `String` is created on each concatenation.

Comment: in this case it should be O(N log N), because we don't copy whole string every time - isn't it?

Comment: @Bor Since the concatenation does `N/2` work on average and it is run `N` times, the total work is `N^2/2` which is `O(N^2)`.